# JQuery click event not triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button on one of my views

```
<div class="span12">
    <button id="saveButton" class="btn"><i class="icon-download-alt green"></i> Save</button>
</div>
```

and a JQuery click event

```
$("#saveButton").click(function () {
    alert("Save clicked"); 
});
```

For some reason the click event is never triggered. 
If I place an alert before the JQuery event the alert is triggered successfully.

I'm sure I'm missing something really simple here, but I cant seem to find the problem.

I made sure that

- JQuery is included successfully
- The javascript file is included successfully
- I use the correct Id for the control

Is there any reason why this event is not triggered?

Comment: Is the html snippet loaded in the initial DOM? If not, then use jquery's `.on()` function.

Comment: You have to make sure the click event listener is declared after the document has loaded. So using jQuery, please see documentation [HERE](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put your code in a document ready handler. Without it jQuery will attempt to attach the `click` event before the element exists in the DOM.

```
$(function() {
    $("#saveButton").click(function () {
        alert("Save clicked"); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#saveButton").click(function () {
      alert("Save clicked"); 
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

please check working fiddle here :

http://jsfiddle.net/6e2q3/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#saveButton").click(function () {
        alert("Save clicked"); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code,

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#saveButton").click(function () {
                    alert("Save clicked"); 
                });
            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="span12">
            <button id="saveButton" class="btn"><i class="icon-download-alt green"></i> Save</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PEFS7/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
$("#saveButton").click(function () {
    alert("Save "); 
});
```

});

hope this will works